# Using @PreAuthorize or @Secured with Jersey when using Configuration Class

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, jersey

I am having a problem similar to [PreAuthorize annotation doesn't work with jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016333/preauthorize-annotation-doesnt-work-with-jersey). I created a configuration class for Spring Security and the authentication works but the authorization does not.

Here is my code

**SpringSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
@ComponentScan({"com.foo.rest.resources.Template"})
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
        this.userService = new UserService();
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .anonymous().and()
                .servletApi().and()
                .headers().cacheControl().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Allow anonymous logins
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                // All other request need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // Custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the client
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        return tokenAuthenticationService;
    }
}
```

and **Template.java**

```
@Component
@Path("/template")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Template {

    @GET
    @Secured("ROLE_EDITOR")
    public User getTemplate() {
        return new Template();
    }
}
```

My guess is that the authentication is handled in the filter chain but it never comes back around after the authorization tag is reached. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Is the user that is accessing the rest service configured with a "ROLE_EDITOR" role in your user service??

Comment: It's just a typo from the original code that has been fixed. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `@ComponentScan` is configured wrongly and doesn't pick the `Template` resource correctly.

According to [`@ComponentScan` documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) the value is an alias for `basePackages` but you have given a Class instead of Package. Try and change it to look like following and see.

```
@ComponentScan({"com.foo.rest.resources.*"})
```

And make sure you haven't missed any steps in Jersey Spring Integration as per the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html)

Comment: There was a mix of things I needed to do, but documentation and your answer got me roughly 90% of the way there.

Comment: user3170736 - do you remember what you ended up doing ? I'm facing the same issue! Cheers